# How to get element Xpath with type select, while the Spy object inside katalon can't find it

Tags: xpath, automation, dropdown, katalon-studio

I am beginner in Katalon, and I am trying to locate the Xpath of a drop down , but the Object Spy can't locate the type select from the following website: https://marketplace.clicdata.com/v/ph1v0wXq5TWE.

**I am using the function :** WebUI.getNumberOfTotalOption(), to get the number of options inside the drop down, but the system returns the following error :  Element should have been "select" but was "div"

**Note:**
I have used the same Object Spy from katalon on different website and I found the correct Xpath of the drop down with type select, and I have used the same function and it works properly.

**Question:**
What I should do in case I didn't find the correct Xpath, and/or how to locate the correct Xpath inside this website.

Second, is there another way or function that allows me to get number of options inside the drop down?

you can find the steps inside the below image

[image]

Comment: Could `count(//div[@class="ui"]//option)` which returns 2 be enough ?

Comment: No it doesn't work , since katalon doesn't found the count function and I already imported all packages. As well I need to check each value inside the drop down if its correct value or not. Also Can't find the correct path of the dropdown.

Comment: The website use dynamic rendering. Once fully loaded, the XPath for the dropdown is : `//ul[@class="widgetDropdown-container"]`. For the values : `//ul[@class="widgetDropdown-container"]//input/@value`. For the default value :`//ul[@class="widgetDropdown-container"]/li[@class="active"]`